# Persistent Store Examples for Blackberry Dont work

Tags: java, blackberry

I've found several examples on Persistent Store and I copy and paste, but I always get an error when building. I have Blackberry Curve 8530. Does anyone have an example that actually works? I have code signing keys to try on phone but always get `Uncaught exception: java.lang.Error` on phone. I'm a newbie to this and really need a working example to see how it works. Other examples say `Warning!: Invocation of questionable method: java.lang.String.<init>(String)` when building. It is at this code every time :

```
public StoreInfo() 
{
    _elements = new Vector(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < _elements.capacity(); ++i) 
    {
        _elements.addElement(new String(""));
    }
}
```

I've searched and searched but this looks correct to me. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, string constants are implicitly stored as String objects. In other words, you can do this:

```
String s = "";
```

If you initialize a string using a string constant, you're creating a String object unnecessarily:

```
String s = new String(""); // redundant!
```

So that explains the questionable invocation method — you don't need to create a String object, just pass the string constant directly to the addElement method.

As for the error you're seeing, we need to see more code. Take a look also at this [BlackBerry object persistence tutorial](http://www.blackberryprogramming.com/tutorials/object-persistence/) for some more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That cured the questionable invocation method, completed build with no errors ! But still pops up error when run on phone. Uncaught exception:java.lang.Error Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Like Eric said, some more code is probably going to be necessary to debug that error.  Also, if you could point out exactly which line where the error occurs, that would help as well.

Comment: After using Eric's correction above i no longer recieve any errors when building file. Starting to think it might be a setting on my phone or something ?